# nodejs sql error Error converting data type varchar to int

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sql-server

I have error from SQL Server:

> Error converting data type varchar to int

My code JS

```
exports.Checkskip = async function(req, res) {
try {
    let a = req.params.TagAlternateKey;
    let b = req.params.ProcessOfProductionKey;
    const pool = await poolPromise;
    const result = await pool.request()
        .query("execute [wos].[StoredInternalProcessTransactionCheckProcessBeforeReceiving ] '"+req.params._TagAlternateKey+"','"+ req.params._ProcessOfProductionKey +"' ",function(err, result)
        {   
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
            else {
                res.json(result.recordset); 
            }
        })
}catch (err){
    res.status(500)
    res.send(err.message)
}
}
```

[image: my data for input]

Can someone help me?

Comment: If you parametrise your query, instead of **insecurely** injecting the values, I bet the problems disappears.

Comment: its also a problem in the DB level - varchar / int are db types

Comment: like this ?                                                                                                                       
let a = req.params.TagAlternateKey;
let b = req.params.ProcessOfProductionKey;                                                                       .query("execute [wos].[StoredInternalProcessTransactionCheckProcessBeforeReceiving ] '"+ a +"','"+ b +"' ",function(err, result)        it not work

Comment: As expected, wos000016 isn't an integer.

Comment: yes wos000016 has a vachar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass parameter to mssql query in node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58851653/how-to-pass-parameter-to-mssql-query-in-node-js) also [How to execute stored procedure as well as select command using nodejs-mssql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37135238/how-to-execute-stored-procedure-as-well-as-select-command-using-nodejs-mssql)